# How to add authentication to CURL Command for Apache NiFi

Tags: authentication, curl, command, apache-nifi

So, I want to start/stop NiFi processors from the command line and I've found resources that help with that command, but it's on a company box so I'll just to use authentication, I can't figure out how to add in my credentials in order to execute the curl command below.

curl -i -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"id":"p6c22191-86e8-3a1f-9ae2-c1982633cdc1 ","state":"RUNNING"}' https://edclsede101.polinmix.com:9091/nifi/?processGroupId=2ca5e75f-6473-3d82-827c-82f744038080&componentIds=p6c22191-86e8-3a1f-9ae2-c1982633cdc1

login: svc- LearnNiFi
password: Premier_Protein12

Comment: I am afraid Nifi does not accept that; you may end up adding certificates to curl request. also as I know there is no way to bypass certificates

Comment: it depends on how you setup auth for nifi. just check how you authenticating in browser and repeat steps in command line - it's possible but requires few scripting steps. as an option there is a nipyapi python library to manage nifi from commandline.